# IBM Worklight 6.0 - GeoLocation API Documentation

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-geolocation

I'm using the `WL.Device.Geo` API. actually, only the  `WL.Device.Geo.acquirePosition`. method documented here: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fapiref%2Fr_wl_location_geoAcquirePosition.html

For the onSuccess method it states:

> A callback function that is invoked when a position is acquired
>   successfully. The position is passed as a parameter to the callback
>   function.

Is it documented anywhere the parameters that are passed to the callback function? I can use, for example, the `JSON.stringify` method for getting the content but this situation is something I have faced more times with the API documentation and I do not know whether or not is it documented, or if there is more detailed API documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback receives a W3C position object (http://www.w3.org/TR/geolocation-API/#position_interface). The timestamp is always the number of milliseconds elapsed since Jan 1, 1970 (the W3C specifies the use of DOMTimestamp - on some platforms this is implemented as the number of milliseconds elapsed, on others it is a Date object. WL.Device.Geo.acquirePosition and updates to the device context when using WL.Device.startAcquisition always use the former).

Comment: Also, documentation will be improved. Thanks @Javier.